# 18.04 audio (Realtek ALC3254) fails on new Dell G3 15 3590

Tags: drivers, 18.04, sound, realtek

Things were working fine for the first three weeks on the new notebook. Then, it stopped recognizing the audio board in a [Dell G3 15 3590](https://www.dell.com/en-us/shop/dell-laptops/dell-g3-15-gaming-laptop/spd/g-series-15-3590-laptop) ([service manual](https://topics-cdn.dell.com/pdf/g-series-15-3590-laptop_service-manual_en-us.pdf)) ([audio specs](https://www.dell.com/support/manuals/us/en/19/g-series-15-3590-laptop/dell-g3-3590-setup-and-specifications/audio)).

I've disabled the secure boot, reinstalled plug audio, fed several different commands into the terminal, but it continues to not give any option for audio output aside from "dummy output".

After the mic and speaker output options disappeared in Configurations, leaving me with only "dummy output" as an option.

I tried:

1. Reinstalled Pulse Audio and rebooted.
2. Disabled Secure Boot.
3. Ran tests with Dell technical support to confirm that the video and audio board and drivers are working, during boot up.
4. Opened the terminal and ran `sudo apt-get install pavucontrol pavucontrol` then entered configuration profile to set configuration to analog stereo out, only to find "dummy output" as the only option again.
5. Opened the terminal and ran `sudo alsa force-reload`.
6. `pulseaudio -k && sudo alsa force-reload` had no effect.
7. BIOS -> disable audio -> boot to Ubuntu -> restart -> BIOS -> enable audio -> boot to Ubuntu did not work. I still have "Dummy output" as the only sound output option.
8. In accordance with instructions given on this conversation threat, I ran "inxi -Fxz && arecord -l && dmesg | grep snd" the result was: Command 'inxi' not found, but can be installed with: sudo apt install inxi
9. I went onto the dell site to see if I could download a new driver for the  Realtek ALC3254 but the only drivers that I could find on the site are only for Windows 10.
10. Regarding the question about updating the bios. I dropped into the bios, audio section and headphone and speaker output are all checked as on. I am sorry but I don't understand how I would update the bios. What I see in the audio section of the bios are 3 options: bios defaults; factory settings; custom user settings. I was thinking of maybe changing to bios defaults and saving, but decided I'd better not start screwing around with bios until I know exactly what I was doing. Would that be something worth trying?
11. installed inxi. Ran `inxi -Fxz`. It reads:
    ``
    Audio: Card-1 NVIDIA Device 10fa driver: snd_nda_intel bus-ID 01:00.1
    Card-2 Intel Cannon Lake PCH CAVS
    Driver: sof-audio-pci bus-ID 00:1f.3
    Sound: Advanced Linux Sound Architecture v: k5.0.0.-1043-oem-osp1

12 (April 12 - one month with no sound on brand new Dell G3 purchased with Ubuntu 18.04) Following Wikihow instructions on how to install a new kernel. After following steps 1-5, then typing sudo apt-get install ukuu i get a message saying  it can't find ukuu

13. Installed Kernel 5.5.9. Nothing changed. Still only getting dummy audio.

``

Dell technical support walked me through some tests to confirm that the audio board and driver is working fine, but they do not provide software support for Ubuntu.

I have now given up on Ubuntu completely. I will now move on to Mint. I have come to the conclusion that, for a lay person with average computer stills Ubuntu is incompatible with the Dell G3 and it is, therefore, a waste of time and money to purchase it with the Ubuntu installation.

Comment: Thank you. My PC is really a  Dell G3 15 3590

Comment: a) Thank you for the details! It makes a solution much easier to find. b) Please go to each of the comments you added above & click _Delete_ at the end of each to make room for more comments. c) Comments are our channel to you; when you  have new info, please use [edit] to put it in the Question. d) #8 is a command specific to Unity Desktop; 18.04 uses GNOME3 Shell instead, unless you specifically installed Unity Desktop or retained it after an upgrade from 16.04 to 18.04. If you didn't specifically install or retain Unity Desktop, please click [edit] and delete 8) in your question.

Comment: e) Please update the BIOS if you have not done so already as per https://www.dell.com/support/article/en-us/sln317706/inspiron-g3-3590-may-have-no-audio-or-sound-when-starting-the-computer-from-a-completely-shutdown-state?lang=en&ref=topsolutions . Have you updated the BIOS? Please click [edit] and advise if you did. f) Your audio is not in the NVIDIA GeForce but instead is by the Realtek ALC3254 processor per https://www.dell.com/support/manuals/us/en/19/g-series-15-3590-laptop/dell-g3-3590-setup-and-specifications/audio

Comment: You're not alone w/ Realtec ALC3254 audio trouble - see  https://askubuntu.com/search?q=ALC3254 & https://github.com/thesofproject/linux/issues/1877 Since at least 1 report was w/Ubuntu 19.10, testing with 19.10 will not help. Reverting to an older kernel did help, though; see https://askubuntu.com/questions/1218058/ubuntu-19-10-audio-driver-issue . Please consider that. Also, please run _inxi -Fxz && arecord -l && dmesg | grep snd_ , highlight the results, copy that text, return here, click [edit] & paste the text into the end of your question.

Comment: I am now wondering if I should try to install an older kernel. If so, does anyone have any recommendations? I need audio for my job.

Comment: Please consider reverting to an older kernel as suggested in https://askubuntu.com/questions/1218058/ubuntu-19-10-audio-driver-issue

Comment: None of this is working. My last resort will be trying to install an older kernel I guess. I am getting very close to just giving up. I am working 12 hour days as a jornalist, need sound to edit my news rushes, and do not have time to teach myself a new operating system which I imagined would have been much more intuitive to use. Thank you for the suggestions, but I feel like Dell screwed me over by selling me a product with an icompatible sound board on it.

Answer (score 8):

Im using Ubuntu 18.04 Dell G3 3590 i7 series

I just follow the instruction here and fixes my problem

Edit `/etc/default/grub`

```
sudo vi /etc/default/grub
```

Find the line starting with `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` and append `snd_hda_intel.dmic_detect=0` to its end. For example:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash snd_hda_intel.dmic_detect=0"
```

Update grub configuration

```
sudo update-grub
```

Reboot

[https://askubuntu.com/questions/1218058/ubuntu-19-10-audio-driver-issue/1238287#1238287](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1218058/ubuntu-19-10-audio-driver-issue/1238287#1238287%5D%5B1%5D)

Comment: It worked on my dell g3 i5 9300H.

Comment: Thank you so much. this worked for me :)

Comment: Just created an account here to vote for this answer and say thanks! I spent a few frustrating hours trying to get my Dell Laptop speakers working with Ubuntu and this solution finally worked!

Answer (score 1):

--- UPDATED VERSION ---

As of Nov. 29 of 2020, update on Ubuntu 20.04 with latest kernel of 5.8.0-25-generic is working as expected with all internal sound working. Basically if you modified your grub with snd_hda_intel.dmic_detect=0, erase that or other modifications you made and keep the system fresh.

Update and upgrade with apt and now it is working with the internal mics and speakers.

So basically, update your vanilla 20.04 with latest kernel and updates and should work.

--- OLD REVISION ---

THIS IS WHAT WORKED FOR ME,

DELL G3 3590 is certified in Ubuntu 18.04 ONLY. It's very weird that later versions break functionality in this laptop.

The Dell G3 3590 version I have is the revised one (2019 version) but I guess the older 3590 version should work as well.

Do not install Ubuntu 20.04 or other version except 18.04 on this notebook.

I just did a Fresh install and at first sound wasn't working, then a Automatic Update at first boot (it's common when fresh install to get an update) added the sound and microphone working. If not, just `apt-get update && apt-get upgrade`

Then I added additional drivers for Nvidia and is working nice.

***UPDATE***
On February aprox. a new version of ubuntu was released (18.04.4) and it has an optional upgrade called HWE that contains newer kernel and stuff. My solution worked but in some point, audio from the headphone jack was missing.

running `sudo apt-get install --install-recommends linux-generic-hwe-18.04 xserver-xorg-hwe-18.04` solved this issue. So I have fresh install ubuntu 18.04.4, updated it and finally updated to HWE and have all sound working! internal and external as well.

WHAT A RIDE!!!

Comment: Weird. I have a Dell Inspiron 7590 and on Ubuntu 21.04 with kernel 5.11.0-22-generic but I still can't have the speakers work out of the box. `dmic_detect=0` is stlll needed to have speakers working, but it disables the mic.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here. Debian 10 installed on a Dell G3 15 3590 with audio issues using Realtek ALC3254.
I've found a page with a lot of information .
The best I've found so far to fix it is in the page below (in french but easily translated) but I didn't succeed, I think I screwed up  some steps...

https://doc.ubuntu-fr.org/audio_intel_hda#dell

If the first elementary tests did not fix you audio, they suggest to:
modify the file /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf
or if it doesnt exist I've found that you can also create a local.conf file with sudo privilege here /etc/modprobe.d/local.conf

=> add the following line at the end of the file:
options snd-hda-intel model=headset-mic probe_mask=0x103

See the line:
Inspiron 15-5578    |
ALC3253     |
options snd-hda-intel model=headset-mic probe_mask=0x103 (Fonctionne: haut-parleurs interne, mic. interne, sortie écouteurs. Ne fonctionne pas: entrée(mic) écouteur)

This is the best I've found so far to fix it.

-

It is likely due to the Realtek driver not correctly working on Linux. 
But I don't know if it is possible to fix this driver on linux?
who could do that ? where to ask ?
I've tries to use bluetooth headset with microphone but it doesn't even want to configure it.

---

Hope This will help a little bit ? Let me know

Bye

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, probably around the same time - [No audio in laptop speakers or headphones, but sound plays in screen (HDMI connection)](https://askubuntu.com/q/1241924/756094), and it was resolved in about 2 months, on its own. My analysis can be found [in this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1256444/756094).

The question is - What was the kernel version at the time you probably started getting this issue? You can check that by using

```sh
zgrep 'install linux-headers' /var/log/dpkg.log* | sort | cut -f1,2,4 -d' '
```

If the timeline of this issue matches mine, as in you started experiencing issue with `4.15.0-99-generic` kernel update, or close, then I would suggest going back to the original kernel version (that you had before manually installing `5.5.9`) and **update to the latest kernel that is available for your system**, instead of a particular kernel, i.e. `5.5.9`, that you installed to resolve the issue but may or may not be compatible with your system, yet.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks!

I had no sounds (speakers and headphones) in my Dell Latitude 3510 with Realtek ALC3204 after installing Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

I have tried a lot of different solutions without any result

After all your solution also worked for me!

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

Find the line starting with `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` and append `snd_hda_intel.dmic_detect=0` to its end.

For example:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash snd_hda_intel.dmic_detect=0"
```

Update grub configuration

```
sudo update-grub
```

Answer (score -1):

same problem here. Using Linux Mint,18.

The kernel I've installed was the 5.0, and the sound worked fine.

When I upgraded to 5.3, the audio stopped working.

Comparing the modules that was loaded in each kernel (lspci -k) I noticed that audio module was not the same, the kernel 5.3 was using sof-audio-pci driver.

Searching, I discovered that solution:

I've just got new HP Spectre x360 15-DF1033DX, installed Arch and got stuck with Audio. No output/input, no sound.

I used to change `/etc/default/grub to have this line`

*GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="loglevel=3 quiet splash acpi_backlight=vendor acpi_osi='!Windows 2013' acpi_osi='!Windows 2012'* **snd_hda_intel.dmic_detect=0** *"*

*Then run in terminal*

```
grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

*Then reboot.*

Link of the solutuion:
https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=251157