# No WiFi Adaptor found, and Dummy output for sound when booting into different kernel

Tags: boot, kernel

Background - I was originally trying to resolve the issue of [Question - No audio in laptop speakers or headphones, but sound plays in screen (HDMI connection)](https://askubuntu.com/q/1241924/756094), I suspected kernel update and with the help from comments in [Question - In the package logs, what are the kernel updates listed as?](https://askubuntu.com/q/1242286/756094), I was able to discern kernel version I wanted to try booting into to see if the issue is resolved.

Right now, I have managed to install the kernels for specific version by installing appropriate `linux-image`(s) and the `linux-header`(s) **only**, but when I do boot using these kernels from the GRUB menu, the OS can not find my WiFi Adaptor, and for the sound it shows "Dummy Output". I installed 3 kernels on top of the existing one, and this issue is happening with them all.

Am I missing a crucial step or detail here?

Comment: Did you also install linux-generic?

Comment: I'm having a similar issue. I have been using Ubuntu 18.04 on this laptop since I got it in 2018. Yesterday suddenly this no sound problem and only Dummy Output shown as the only option for device under sound output in settings. But I still had wifi yesterday and now that is gone too, showing "no wifi adapter found" in settings. I'm not really a tech person, would really appreciate a simple easy to follow solution for whatever weird malady is affecting my system.

Comment: You know what resolved it for me in the end - installing all updates. I was running dual boot with Windows. I went ahead and installed every update that I had been ignoring - windows, bios, and ubuntu. Something in there just fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

> I have managed to install the kernels for specific version by
>   installing appropriate linux-image(s) and the linux-header(s) only

In order to get the required kernel modules; that is drivers for wireless, ethernet and many more, you also needed to install linux-modules-xxx-generic as well as linux-modules-extra-xxx-generic, where xxx is the kernel version that you installed. Find out with the terminal command:

```
uname -r
```

It appears that this step was missed.

If you installed these kernels from the preferred Ubuntu repositories, you can go here and find the debs to install: https://packages.ubuntu.com/

If you installed these kernels from Ubuntu mainline, for example, here: https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.6/ then you will notice that there is, in addition to linux-image and linux-headers, a package called linux-modules. Wireless, ethernet and many other drivers are included.

If you installed these kernels from some other source, please specify so that we may help you further.

Comment: Thank you. The `linux-modules-xxx-generic` was already installed, I found out  when I tried to, but `linux-modules-extra-xxx-generic`, I had to install. After I did, the wifi is working the sound is still not. I think you are right about what I missed. Do you know which particular package I might have missed to install for the audio drivers?

Comment: Not without knowing what sound device you have. `sudo lshw -C multimedia` Have you tried selecting a different output device in Settings > Sound?