# Headset microphone and speaker not working on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, microphone, headset

I own Dell Inspiron 7591 with Windows 10 and Ubuntu 20.04 dual boot.
I connected my headset via 3.5mm audio jack while on Ubuntu. In the 'Input Device' list in Sound Settings I get following 3 options:

1. Digital Microphone-Cannon Lake PCH cAVS
2. Headphones Stereo Microphone-Cannon Lake PCH cAVS
3. Headset Mono Microphone-Cannon Lake PCH cAVS

The 'Output Device' is the Headphone. The headset speakers work only when the 3rd option is selected. Also, the headset mic does not work in any case.

Changing headset yields the exact same problem. I also tried `alsactl restore` but that does not fix it either. Can someone help with this?

Comment: This [fix](https://askubuntu.com/a/1223057/867028) worked for me..