# How do I pop-up "select audio device" from command line?

Tags: 18.04, gnome, audio-jack

I would like to know which function on command line that pops up "select audio device":

[image]

Comment: Hi, I am going through your Question, Whats the use case? When do you want to pop it? Once you connected the real one and after choosing the option and then later on you want to pop it? Or without connecting any device?

Comment: I will put that command on .profile when the desktop is loaded. Reason: I have Dell laptop and unexpectedly it started to fail to select headset. I used this solution to solve it: https://askubuntu.com/a/1238292/530032 , but I still have to plug in and plug off when I boot ubuntu.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to run the below command,

```
gdbus call --session --dest org.gnome.Shell.AudioDeviceSelection --object-path /org/gnome/Shell/AudioDeviceSelection --method org.gnome.Shell.AudioDeviceSelection.Open "['HEADPHONES', 'HEADSET', 'MICROPHONE']"
```

[image]

I am not able to reproduce your use case, as I dont have resources like headset or microphone. So I doubt the Options from above command really activates your choice. Try it.