# Ubuntu not showing 'Select audio device' pop up

Tags: sound

I inserted an external microphone but Ubuntu detects it as headset.

[image: Sound settings]

If it shows select audio device popup, I can select it as mic, but it doesn't show. Any solutions for this?

Comment: There's no such popups in Ubuntu. Maybe you're thinking Windows?

Comment: Have a look at https://askubuntu.com/questions/1283328/how-do-i-pop-up-select-audio-device-from-command-line